# my php form wont submit into database even though connection is working

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values

$isbn = $ISBN = $title = $Title = $pubdate = $PubDate = $pubid = $PubID = $cost = $Cost = $retail = $Retail = $category = $Category = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if (isset($_POST["ISBN"])) {
        $isbn = trim($_POST["ISBN"]);
        echo "Yes, ISBN is set";    
    }else{  
        echo "N0, ISBN is not set";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["Title"])) {
        $title = trim($_POST["Title"]);
        echo "Title set";
    } else 
        echo "Title not set";

    if (isset($_POST["PubDate"])) {
        $pubdate = trim ($_POST ["PubDate"]);
        echo "PubD set";
    } else 
        echo "PubD not set";

    if (isset($_POST["PubID"])) {
        $pubid = trim ($_POST ["PubID"]);
        echo "PubID set";
    } else 
        echo "PubID not set";

    if (isset($_POST["Cost"])) {
        $cost = trim ($_POST["Cost"]);
        echo "Cost set";
    } else 
        echo "Cost not set";

    if (isset($_POST["Retail"])) {
        $retail = trim ($_POST["Retail"]);
        echo "retail set";
    } else 
        echo "retail not set";

    if (isset($_POST["Category"])) {
        $category = trim($_POST ["Category"]);
        echo "Category set";
    } else 
        echo "Category not set";

    $isbn_err="no isbn";
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($isbn_err) ) {

        // Prepare an insert statement

        $sql = "INSERT INTO books VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("issssss ", $isbn, 
                                        $title,
                                        $pubdate,
                                        $pubid,
                                        $cost,
                                        $retail,
                                        $category);

            // Set parameters
            $isbn= $ISBN;
            $title = $Title ;
            $pubdate = $PubDate;
            $pubid = $PubID ;
            $cost   = $Cost ;
            $retail = $Retail;
            $category = $Category;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()) {
                echo "starting query";
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page

                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo $stmt->error; //"Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        // Close statement  
        $stmt->close(); 
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close(); 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Student Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Create Student Record</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Fill this form correctly to create a new student in ABIIT's database.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"method="post">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>ISBN</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ISBN" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                       <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>TITLE</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>PUB Date</label>
                            <input type="text" name="PubDate" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>PUBID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="PubID" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>Cost</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Cost" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>retail</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Retail" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>

                       </div>

                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label>category</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Category" class="form-control" value="">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>

                       </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
            </div>         
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is supposed to insert the 7 values entered into the form into the database

Made sure i double checked connection bind variables and other issues that may have occured

Have Validation for whether or not variables are being set

All variables are initialized with empty values at default

Trying to get the form submitted however it does not submit or redirect the page anywhere

currently have no idea where the issue may be

tried everything at this point not sure if it may be something with the server method, form action or something else

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback i had no idea of how to enable this or what it does as i am still new to the language i've found the issue

Answer (score 1):

The database update code will never run because of these 2 lines of code.

First you set `$isbn_err="no isbn";` and then you test to see if it is `if(empty($isbn_err) )` and of course as you gave is a value it will NEVER be empty, so you will never enter the block of code that does your database access.

```
$isbn_err="no isbn";
// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($isbn_err) ) {

    // your db code was here
```

Comment: i put the error as a condition inside of the isset statement thank you